# How to print the extracted texts obtained from the web page with a space delimiter using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, delimiter

With the code `String result = driver.findElement (By.id ("ulDezenas")).GetText ();` I can get the result **001122334455**, which is present in uldezenas.
I want to get the numbers, however separated, in this way **00 11 22 33 44 55**.

I already tried the split command, but I could not, unfortunately.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="numbers diaDeSorte" id="ulDezenas">
    <li>00</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>33</li>
    <li>44</li>
    <li>55</li>
    <li>66</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the numbers separately in the following fashion, **`00 11 22 33 44 55`** etc you need to create a *List* you can use either of  of the elements and then use [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) Class to add the *space* character and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) of *Java 8* and later

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.numbers.diaDeSorte#ulDezenas li"));
    ArrayList<String> values = new  ArrayList<>();
    for(WebElement element:elementList)
        values.add(element.getText());
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
    for (String item : values)
        joiner.add(item.toString());
    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='numbers diaDeSorte' and @id='ulDezenas']//li"));
    ArrayList<String> values = new  ArrayList<>();
    for(WebElement element:elementList)
        values.add(element.getText());
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
    for (String item : values)
        joiner.add(item.toString());
    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
    ```
- Using [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) of *Java 9* and later

  ```
  List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.numbers.diaDeSorte#ulDezenas li"));
  ArrayList<String> values = new  ArrayList<>();
  for(WebElement element:elementList)
      values.add(element.getText());
  System.out.println(values.stream().
                  map(Object::toString).
                  collect(Collectors.joining(" ")).toString());
  ```
- Using *org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='numbers diaDeSorte' and @id='ulDezenas']//li"));
  ArrayList<String> values = new  ArrayList<>();
  for(WebElement element:elementList)
      values.add(element.getText());
  System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(values," "));
  ```

Comment: Result:
01
02
03

I want everyone to be on the same line and separated by 1 space 01 02 03, is it possible?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 1):

Get the parent(ul) webelement first; then find elements by tag name 'li' which returns a list. Iterate over it and get the text.

WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.id("ulDezenas"));

```
    for (WebElement li : ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"))) {
        System.out.println(li.getText());
    }
```